# VBA JSON Parsing with VBA-Web Assistance

Tags: json, vba, ms-access

I have some JSON parsing in VBA that's driving me nuts. Here's a sample response:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "access_user",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Me",
                "email": null,
                "phone": null,
                "department": "",
                "status": "current",
                "source": null,
                "guest_source": null,
                "created_at": "2019-08-19T21:45:56Z",
                "updated_at": "2019-08-22T03:38:33Z",
                "pin": "77005",
                "card_number": null
            },
            "id": "be66e054-5509-4cf6-a5c2-14b85eb25619",
            "links": {
                "self": "https://api"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "access_user",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Day Code",
                "email": null,
                "phone": null,
                "department": null,
                "status": "current",
                "source": null,
                "guest_source": null,
                "created_at": "2019-08-21T19:49:29Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-06-16T16:08:28Z",
                "pin": "12345",
                "card_number": null
            },
            "id": "3a615a3d-eb1c-4973-9e9f-ace5e29ca964",
            "links": {
                "self": "https://api"
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "page": 1,
        "per_page": 25,
        "total_count": 2,
        "total_pages": 1
    }
}
```

Traversing "data" is fine, but when I traverse "attributes" I'm getting a "Type mismatch" error. Here's my code. I'm not seeing anything wrong. Any thoughts?

```
For Each Item In Response2.Data("data")
    UserType = Item("type")
    Id = Item("id")
    If UserType = "access_user" Then
        For Each Nested In Item("attributes")
            Name = Nested("name")
            status = Nested("status")
            PIN = Nested("pin")
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Anyone's assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The following two lines are equivalent . . .

```
For Each Nested In Item("attributes")
```

and

```
For Each Nested In Item("attributes").Keys()
```

So, in fact, you're looping through each key within the dictionary.  And so your control variable `Nested` is assigned a string, hence the type mismatch.

Since `Item("attributes")` returns a dictionary object, you can eliminate the `For Each/Next` loop, and you can access your items as follows . . .

```
    Name = Item("attributes")("name")
    Status = Item("attributes")("status")
    PIN = Item("attributes")("pin")
```